# Can food or drinks be Kosher without an Hechsher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Say i pick up a drink in a gas station and i know that all the ingredients are Kosher, can i drink it? Or do i have to be Concerned for Beliyos from the non-Kosher machinery (Perhaps they get batel beshishim)?

Comment: The title and body of your post don't really match

Comment: How do you know that it's kosher, even if it has  100% natural ingredients? If it has no hechsher, as you have stated, of course you have to worry what machinery has processed it. The only way you would know is if you supervised and saw the full processing itself.

Comment: The issue is not just Beliyos but BeAin.

Comment: @DanF Perhaps they get batel beshishim - quote from the question

Comment: @ShmuelBrin As you've implied, whole bugs are not batel. Which, of course, puts bottled water into question, perhaps.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin what do u mean with Beain? perhaps you mean Birya?

Comment: @Bach meening how do you know 1. What all ingredients are 2. What all the ingredients mean?

Comment: @Bach "beain" means something like "substantive" or "in existence" or "massive" (in the sense of "having mass")